# Update a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, updates

I use a Menu of "code4app.net" for my app and I have a problem. Source is here : [click here](http://code4app.net/ios/SlideMenuControllerSwift/54be0ed4e247412c488b4567)

I update a global var in one controller:

```
  func sendGlobalData(){
    globalCurrentUser = currentUser
}
```

and I use it in another:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setBackButton()
    self.setNavigationBarItem()
    userProfilePicture.profileID = globalCurrentUser.profilePictureID
    userNameLabel.text = globalCurrentUser.username

}
```

When I click on a menu's button I need to call again this viewDidLoad function.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewDidLoad() method its automatically called during view controller lifecycle and you should not call it manually. To update your label from other view controller you should use notification center. If you are unfamiliar with it a good starting point might be [this](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/) tutorial